# Extract value of name in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose I have a pandas Series:

```
0        Mary
1       Annie
2        Anna
3    Margaret
4       Helen
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

and I want to convert that to be json file, like this:

```
[
  {
   "Nama":"Mary"
  },
  {
   "Nama":"Annie"
  },
  {
   "Nama":"Anna"
  },
  {
   "Nama":"Margaret"
  },
  {
   "Nama":"Helen"
  }

]
```

I hope my question is clear enough. Anyone has an idea how to get that json file?

Answer (score 2):

Select column by double `[]` for one column `DataFrame` and use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
j = df[['Name']].to_json(orient='records')
print (j)
[{"Name":"Mary"},{"Name":"Annie"},{"Name":"Anna"},{"Name":"Margaret"},{"Name":"Helen"}]
```

Or if want dictionaries use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
L = df[['Name']].to_dict(orient='records')
print (L)
[{'Name': 'Mary'},{'Name': 'Annie'},{'Name': 'Anna'},{'Name': 'Margaret'},{'Name': 'Helen'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a DataFrame like proposed by @jezrael, you can use this code (s is your Series):

```
json_res = [{s.name: v} for v in s.to_list()]
print(json_res)
[{'name': 'Mary'},
 {'name': 'Annie'},
 {'name': 'Anna'},
 {'name': 'Margaret'},
 {'name': 'Helen'}]
```